# Copying rows to the same table without listing the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a stored proc which has to copy existing rows based on a condition into the same table and deactivate existing records by setting active flag column value to 0.

I tried `insert into [tablename] select * from [tablename] where [condition]` obviously, I got an error due to primary key constraint, mentioning column list excluding primary key column in the select will work but there are multiple tables and some tables have around 300 columns. I don't want to give a long list in the select. As I use SQL Server there is a solution that I found here on SO by getting column list from `information_schema.columns` and preparing a dynamic query. However, I am not satisfied with any of those solutions is there any other way that I can do this?

Comment: Listing out all the columns is recommended in any database.  In SQL Server, you seem aware of the two solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find any other solutions other than those two. If listing out all the columns is like a best practice and there is no other way around. I'm fine with that.

Comment: **UNTESTED and BAD PRACTICE** I _believe_ you can create a temp table (not a variable) without defining any columns.  Then you can select * into that temp table using the rows you want to copy.  Then you can update the primary key either in the actual table or in the temp table.  Then you can update the flag to 0 in the actual table.  Finally insert into the table from the temp table.  Don't forget to drop the temp table.

Comment: @avery_larry only works if OP's PK isn't an identity column.

Comment: Why do you have to copy rows over and then "disable" previous batch? Why not just leave them in place?